# Wordpress paginate custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I have a page called News (using page template `page-newslist.php`), which is supposed to display posts from the custom post type also named News. I realize that having both with the same name causes issues, so when registering the custom post type, I have a rewrite to differentiate it from the page:

```
'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'news-article', 'with_front' => true),
```

I can get the query working and displaying the posts properly, but after all of the [articles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325682/wordpress-custom-post-type-pagination) [and](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/wordpress/paginate-custom-post-types/) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12955950/create-pagination-for-custom-post-types-in-wordpress) I've read, I cannot get the pagination to work. Nothing ever shows up for the pagination.

After no success with using the page template query, I tried the `archive-news.php` method, where it would automatically display the posts from the custom post type. The pagination *does* work there. The downside of using this method is that there isn't a 'physical' page to tie it to (which would also have custom fields, ability to be nicely added (not hard-coded) into menus, etc.)

Here is the stripped-down code registering the custom post type:

```
register_post_type('news', array(
    'label' => 'News',
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'news-article', 'with_front' => true),
    'query_var' => true,
    'has_archive' => true,
));
```

And then the code for the page template:

```
$paged = 1;  
if ( get_query_var('paged') ) $paged = get_query_var('paged');  
if ( get_query_var('page') ) $paged = get_query_var('page');
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'news',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'paged' => $paged
);

$my_query = null;
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);

if($my_query->have_posts()):

while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();

...

endwhile;

endif;

wp_reset_query();

// Attempt method 1
posts_nav_link(' — ', __('&laquo; Newer Posts'), __('Older Posts &raquo;'));

// Attempt method 2
previous_posts_link('&laquo; Newer');
next_posts_link('Older &raquo;');
```

Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: Have a look at next page link page, the example here will help. http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/next_posts_link

Comment: Wow, that's what did it. I can't believe after all of the Codex searching I did, I didn't come across that. Thanks! Wish I could accept it as an answer.

Comment: Have added it as an answer to help others so doesn't show as unanswered. Glad I could help.

Comment: it was never explained which method he used in the end, the archive-news.php method or the custom page with template method?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at next page link page, the example here will help. codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/next_posts_link

```
<?php next_posts_link('Older Entries »', 0); ?>
```

Wordpress codex example.

```
        <?php
    // set the "paged" parameter (use 'page' if the query is on a static front page)
    $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

    // the query
    $the_query = new WP_Query( 'cat=1&paged=' . $paged ); 
    ?>

    <?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>



  <?php
    // the loop
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); 
    ?>
    <?php the_title(); ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php

    // next_posts_link() usage with max_num_pages
    next_posts_link( 'Older Entries', $the_query->max_num_pages );
    previous_posts_link( 'Newer Entries' );
    ?>

    <?php 
    // clean up after our query
    wp_reset_postdata(); 
    ?>

    <?php else:  ?>
    <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: It's also worth nothing that after I changed `$my_query` to `$wp_query`, it seemed to fix some of the issues with other pagination methods not working (such as the WP-PageNavi plugin).

Answer (score 6):

> ### Pagination Like :  Prev 1 2 3 Next

```
<?php 
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

$news= new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type'=>'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'paged' => $paged,
));

if($news->have_posts()) :
    while($news->have_posts())  : $news->the_post();
            the_title();
    endwhile;

    $total_pages = $news->max_num_pages;

    if ($total_pages > 1){

        $current_page = max(1, get_query_var('paged'));

        echo paginate_links(array(
            'base' => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',
            'format' => '/page/%#%',
            'current' => $current_page,
            'total' => $total_pages,
            'prev_text'    => __('« prev'),
            'next_text'    => __('next »'),
        ));
    }
    ?>    
<?php else :?>
<h3><?php _e('404 Error&#58; Not Found', ''); ?></h3>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata();?>
```

Comment: Its showing pagination but when i click one second pagination page then the content remain same.How to solve this?

Comment: Can you please tell me which permalink structure do you have use?