# Wordpress home page custom post pagination not working in

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I have used CPT & ACF plugins for for custom post. Now problem is pagination showing but when I click on pagination number its not working and showing page not found. **But same code working on any other pages.**  Why its not working in the front/home page?

```
global $wp_query;
$temp     = $wp_query; 
$wp_query   = null; 
$wp_query   = new WP_Query(); 
$wp_query->query('showposts=2&post_type=wordpress_theme&orderby=menu_order&order=ASC'.'&paged='.$paged); 
while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();

    the_title();
    the_field('theme_short_description');

endwhile;

  echo paginate_links( array(
    'prev_text' => __('«'),
    'next_text' => __('»'),
  ) );
  $wp_query = null; 
  $wp_query = $temp;  // Reset
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wordpress paginate custom post type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22843229/wordpress-paginate-custom-post-type)